# Calling MySQL stored procedure in python with field names

Tags: mysql, python

I am trying to call a MySQL stored procedure that returns a single row, I can get the values back back using `cursor.callproc()` and `cursor.stored_results()`, but I can't get name of the field back 'fileHash'

If I call the SP directly I get results such as:

```
mysql> call GetAllFileHashesForDirectory('/myroot/');
+------------------+
| fileHash         |
+------------------+
| testa            |
| testb            |
+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But, when I try and get the field name I get the following instead of 'fileHash':

```
(u'@_GetAllFileHashesForDirectory_arg1',)
```

The python code I use to get the value is:

```
self.__mySQLCursor.column_names
```

Do I need to specify the name in a stored procedure?  I am really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put logic in the stored procedure to `SELECT 'fileHash'` and then [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) that with the query that returns the other values from the other query in the stored procedure and ensure the very first row returned is `fileHash`

```
SELECT 'fileHash'
UNION 
SELECT <column> FROM <table>
```

**Output**

```
+------------------+
| fileHash         |
+------------------+
| fileHash         |
| testa            |
| testb            |
+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the late answer, but I really do not think the chosen answer is good advice, the python mysql module has a method for this already, no need to do weird manips in the ddb. For this, just do:

```
cursor.callproc('sql_procedure', arguments)
for colid in cursor.stored_results():
    columnsProperties = (colid.description)
    print ([column[0] for column in columnsProperties])
```

you get all properties of the column in `colid.description`, the first property is the filename which is what you're after.